# How do I append an array to a wordfilter (greasemonkey + jquery)?

Tags: jquery, arrays, greasemonkey

i want to make a wordfilter, that will replace own chosen words to others, e.g. "ball" -> "circle" and "orange" -> "yellow"

my script so far:

```
<textarea id="banwords">ball:circle, orange:yellow</textarea>
```

this will be saved as

```
GM_setValue("banwords", $("#banwords").val());
```

this is the old replacement script, but now i want to get the words from GM_getValue("banwords"):

```
$(".t").each(function(i,el) {  
    el = $(el);
    el.find(":contains('ball')").replaceWith("circle");
    el.find(":contains('orange')").replaceWith("yellow");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating the answer, hope this would help you

```
$(".t").each(function(){
   var e1 = $(this).find('#banwords');
    var values = e1.text().split(", ");
    $.each(values, function(i,value){
        var val = value.split(":");
        e1.text(e1.text().replace(val[0],val[1]));
     });
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rYf2f/2/

Comment: but that doesnt grab the words from the textarea, because if there was something else in the textarea it wouldnt be replaced

Comment: but if another user would write in the textarea: nice:cool, sweet:roll then your script wouldnt work

Comment: well i have updated the code and fiddle, hope this time it will help you.